# Filter Drop-down values based on logged user

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app, custom-web-parts

I should create a drop down box to display hosted-app part, based on the selected value from drop down box. Also I need to filter the drop down values based on logged user. And this need to be done with SharePoint-O365. Any help would be highly appreciate..

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: What have you done so far? Share your work/code?

Comment: @YashSaraiya, Currently I'm using separate pages with web parts. Have Drop down box in navigation with values links to those pages.

Comment: Use javascript to achieve this.

Comment: @TaranGoel I've tried with I frame, but its not working. To be brief, I've created app and deployed to separate page. Then in default page, I created drop down with Iframe(used script editor webpart) to show that app page. But It removes the scripts once I save that webpart. Is there any other way to achieve it??